# How to initialize a class variable using a for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, class, static

My example class has a static array of characters, and I want to create a map from the characters to the indices. I need to initialize this static map in a for loop in my "example.cpp" file. However, C++ "expects a declaration". Is there any way of populating my map as a declaration? In general, is it possible to create a constructor for the static variables that handles all this initialization before the constructor for the class variables is called?

Here is my example class.

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class Example {
    static char chars[4];
    static map<char,int> char2idx;
};

char Example::chars[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};
for(int i=0; i<4;i++) {
    Example::char2idx[Example::chars[i]] = i;
}
```

I am getting the following error when I try to compile.

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g -c -o example.o example.cpp
example.cpp:9:1: error: expected unqualified-id
for(int i=0; i<4;i++) {
^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: C++ does not work this way. All code in a C++ program must be in a function, or a class method.

Comment: Preferably: in a standalone function invoked by `main` or someplace where common initialization is done. Or [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).  Worse solution: an instance of another class defined at global scope that has a constructor do the work. (I'd never approve your pull-request on my team to do it this way).

Comment: A `for` loop is only permitted in the body of a function.   In any event, you can initialise your map as `std::map<char, int> Example::char2idx { {'a', 0}, {'b', 1}, {'c', 2}, {'d', 3}};`.   No need for the `chars` array at all (unless you need it for some other purpose).     Bear in mind that `static` members are often considered poor practice.  While there are a few circumstances where they are useful or a reasonable idea, beginners tend to use them instead of better alternatives - I suspect that is the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ur-example in C++ is how `std::cin`, `std::cout`, etc are initialized. The core trick is to have a local static variable in the global namespace that calls the static constructor:

`example.hpp`

```
class Example
{
  static stuff here;
  static bool initialize();
};

static bool b_initialize_Example = Example::initialize();
```

`example.cpp`

```
bool Example::initialize()
{
  static bool is_initialized = false;
  if (!is_initialized)
  {
    // do your for loop here.
  }
  return is_initialized = true;
}
```

Anther way is to use a **factory** to generate instances of your class. The first time you generate an instance, initialize the static data.

```
// No example here. Google around factory methods.
// You’ll still need a static bool is_initialized somewhere.
```

Finally, you can just use a static initializer in your class’s constructor. This is similar to the first method:

```
class Example
{
  Example() { initialize(); ... }

  static void initialize()
  {
    static bool is_initialized = false;
    if (is_initialized) return;
    // initialize stuff here
    is_initialized = true;
  }
};
```

I’m sure there are other ways to go about this, but that’s what is on the top of my head.

EDIT: the example in the other answer is nice too!

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix: Make a helper function

```cpp
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class Example {
    friend map<char,int> helper(); // so it can see the private members
    static char chars[4];
    static map<char,int> char2idx;
};

map<char,int> helper() // does the work, returns the map
{
    map<char,int> out;
//    for(int i=0; i<4;i++) {  that four is ugly. What if chars changes in size?
    for(int i=0; i<std::size(Example::chars);i++) { // if we didn't want i I'd use 
                                                    // a range-based for to make 
                                                    // life even simpler.  
        out[Example::chars[i]] = i;
    }
    return out; // return by value. copy elision is your friend!
}


char Example::chars[4] = {'a','b','c','d'};
map<char,int> Example::char2idx = helper();
```

Comment: If the function isn't going to be reused, you can make it an immediately evaluated lambda : https://godbolt.org/z/776zj6YYo